# Hiding or not displaying excel VBA UDF module/code

Tags: vba, excel, udf

I wrote a simple UDF in Excel VBA. I saved it as an Add-in and imported it in so that I can use the function like any other excel function. But whenever I open an Excel workbook and subsequently VBA window to create a macro, the module I wrote is displayed in the Project Explorer window and its code in the coding window.

Is there any way I can hide or not display every time I open VBA?

Please let me know if you need more information. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If it is in your project you are going to be able to see it.  I suppose you could make it into a library and reference it into the project.

Comment: Did you maybe save the script in a module in "Personal.xlsb"?

Comment: He's not asking whether we can see modules in a project; that's obvious, of course you can. The annoyance is that every time he opens the VBE, that particular module appears automatically in the CODE window. I'm here chasing the same problem, and curiously, mine is also a module containing UDF's, leading me to suspect that this is something "helpful" that the VBE is programmed to do. As usual, over-thinking by programmers leads to anti-help. The answer probably lies in learning more about VBIDE, and interfering with the VBE's "helpfulness" directly. If I find time for that, I'll report back he